# How can I use $\LaTeX$ symbol \Perp (from pxfonts/txfonts) in mathjax?

Tags: support, mathjax

The title says it all: How can I use math symbol \Perp (like $\perp$ but with two verticals) from txfonts/pxfonts in mathjax?  It is sometimes used in probability to denote independence.

Comment: $\perp\!\!\!\perp$ = `$\perp\!\!\!\perp$`

Comment: Thanks!  Let us try: $\newcommand{\Perp}{\perp\!\!\!\perp}$ $\Perp$

Comment: This one: $\perp\,\!\,\!\,\!\,\!\,\!\,\!\,\!\!\!\!\perp$ is even nicer but more complicated: `$\perp\,\!\,\!\,\!\,\!\,\!\,\!\,\!\!\!\!\perp$`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `\unicode{x2AEB}`, but note that this character is not in the MathJax TeX fonts, so it would rely on the user having a font with this character installed on their system.  The STIX fonts are one such set of fonts, and if you are authoring your own pages,  you could configure MathJax to use the STIX-Web font so that it would be available.

Answer (score 3):

The solutions using the negative space `\!` gave me problems with wrong spacing in mathjax, and I wanted to avoid setting up a font just for this, so I found the following alternative:

```
\newcommand{\Perp}{\mathrel{\rlap{\perp}\mkern1mu\perp}}
```

$\newcommand{\Perp}{\mathrel{\rlap{\perp}\mkern1mu\perp}}A \Perp B$

Comment: Looks like it works to me. Is this not the desired output? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fae0R.png

Comment: @CalvinKhor: weird, now it works for me too! Maybe I made a typo while trying it. I modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: at certain zooms (and only if I'm using the XITS fonts) the base is [slightly misaligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyFez.png).